# Comparing Strings What is compared?

Tags: java, string, comparator, string-comparison

i have two Strings:

```
String s1 ="11:7:34"
String s2="11:34:34"
```

when i compare the boths Strings, i get as result : false

```
(s1.compareTo(s2) < 0)
```

but when i compare this Strings i get True:

```
String s1 ="11:07:34"
String s2="11:34:34"
```

So my question is, what will be in this case comparised? the lenght of Strings or character of Strings or what? i think "11:07:34" and "11:7:34" should provide the same result!!

Comment: how should the string notify that it should compare dates? providing the logic for this is your job. This comparison simply compares char after char and checks which one would be higher or lower in an lexograpical sort.

Comment: [The `compareTo()` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural ordering of Strings is lexicographical order. The first position in which the two Strings contain different characters determines the result of the comparison.

```
s1 11:7:34
s2 11:34:34     // the first non equal characters are 7 and 3, 7 comes after 3
      _         // so s1 comes after s2 (i.e. s1.compareTo(s2) > 0)


s1 11:07:34
s2 11:34:34     // the first non equal characters are 0 and 3, 3 comes after 0
      _         // so s1 comes before s2 (i.e. s1.compareTo(s2) < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are compared character for character. As `7` is not smaller than `3`, but `0` is, your result is expected. Your semantics of H:m:s are not recognized by `String.compareTo`.

Answer (score 2):

it compares the alphabetical/ numerical order.

Therefore, the order is

"11:0"
"11:3"
"11:7"

Answer (score 1):

You can read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-):

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a
>   negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the
>   argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String
>   object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is
>   zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the
>   equals(Object) method would return true.
>
> This is the definition of
>   lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they
>   have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both
>   strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have
>   different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the
>   smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has
>   the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator,
>   lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the two character values at position k in
>   the two string -- that is, the value:

```
this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
```

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter
>   string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case,
>   compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that
>   is, the value:

```
this.length()-anotherString.length()
```

Answer (score 1):

You think that it should give the same result, because you are able to interpret the strings as times. Java does not know that the strings represent time values.

As the others stated, strings are compared character for character and thus `3` is smaller than `7`.

You should consider to convert your strings to a class that represents a time. For example using the new Java 8 Date and Time API:

```
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse(s1);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse(s2);
```

Then you can compare the new values using

```
t1.compareTo(t2) < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

it gona compare charcter by charcter with ASCII code . 
by the way it's not a good idea to compare time in that way